# Prove that {F,→} is functionally complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Should I prove that I can write all $∧, ∨, ↔ $ only by using $F$ and $→$ or is it easier to prove in some other way?

I have already solved that

$A∧B ≡ (A→(B→F))→F$

$A∨B ≡ ((A→F)→B)$

How can I write the equivalence only using $F$ and $→$?

edit: I got the equivalence too, isn't it:

$A↔B ≡ ((A→B)→((B→A)→F))→F$

Comment: To begin with, what is $F$?

Comment: F is falsum, $⊥$

Comment: For the equivalence, note that $A \leftrightarrow B \equiv (A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B \rightarrow A)$

Comment: You already showed how to write $\land $ using "false" and "implies", so use that to express two-sided implication  (logical "equivalence").

Comment: And recall that $\lnot A$ is $A \to \text F$ (i.e. $A \to \bot$).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully proven that $\{F,\rightarrow\}$ is functionally complete in your attempt.

Another approach would be to prove that you can write all of $\land,\lor,\color{blue}{\lnot}$ instead, noting that $\lnot A\equiv A\rightarrow F$.

One of the shortest approaches would be to show that you can write NAND, [which is a functionally complete on its own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness): NAND$(A,B)\equiv(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow F))$